# zen-coding.vim not working for me (pathogen)

Tags: vim, macvim

So, I've just installed the [zen-coding.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981) plugin and expansions aren't  happening.  The plugin is there if I do scriptnames, and :verbose map  shows the ZenCoding mappings.  However, if I edit an html file (or set ft=html) and type

h1#title

Nothing happens.  I am sure my .vimrc is hosed, but I am a bit new to the vim world so I am struggling finding out what I've messed up.  My vim setup is [here](https://github.com/ruprict/dotvim).  I am on Mac OSX and I am using pathogen to bundle my plugins.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Glenn

Output of :set rtp

runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/IndexedSearch,~/.vim/bundle/gist,~/.vim/bundle/jquery,~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree,~/.
vim/bundle/snipmate.vim,~/.vim/bundle/textile.vim,~/.vim/bundle/vim-align,~/.vim/bundle/vim-cucumber,~/.vim/bundle/
vim-fugitive,~/.vim/bundle/vim-git,~/.vim/bundle/vim-haml,~/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown,~/.vim/bundle/vim-rails,~/.vim
/bundle/vim-repeat,~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby,~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby-debugger,~/.vim/bundle/vim-shoulda,~/.vim/bundle/v
im-supertab,~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround,~/.vim/bundle/vim-tcomment,~/.vim/bundle/vim-vividchalk,~/.vim/bundle/zencoding-vim,/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles,/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/ru
ntime,/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/after,~/.vim/after

Comment: Are both zencoding scripts loaded?  Both a plugin/zencoding.vim and an autoload/zencoding.vim should probably be loaded.

Comment: Nope. just the plugin.  Any idea why the autoload isn't loading?  Have I messed up pathogen?

Comment: Can you post the output of `:set rtp?`

Comment: I don't know about you, but on my setup I have to type `<C-y>,` to get the zen-coding expansion to occur.

Comment: @Randy...added.  The autoload stuff isn't getting loaded.  I thought pathogen would just take care of that...hmmmm...

Comment: Does someone have zen-coding working with pathogen?  Can you show me your rtp?

Comment: So, I blew away my whole dotvim setup and copied [akitaonrails](https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles) dotvim files, instaled zen-coding as a plugin, and it still doesn't work.  I am gonna try Sparkup, I guess. Sigh.  Thanks for trying to help, tho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working by putting this in my .vimrc:

```
let g:user_zen_expandabbr_key = '<c-e>' 
let g:use_zen_complete_tag = 1
```

(I used `<c-e>` instead of the default  mostly because that's what I'm used to from using other editors with Zen Coding)

P.S. For me, Sparkup wasn't really an option since one of my favorite features of zen coding is the "wrap in abbreviation" which Sparkup doesn't support (yet).

Comment: Note that zen-coding.vim has been renamed to emmet.vim as of today so you'll need to replace "zen" with "emmet" in the above options starting now. http://mattn.github.com/emmet-vim

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Pathogen doesn't explicitly include the "after" directories found within plugins that you place in your "bundle" directory. What this means is that plugins such as zen-coding and snipMate fail to run their initialization/cleanup/key binding routines.

Apparently these plugins have worked fine for other folks in other environments, but for me in Windows, snipMate wouldn't work because the final snippet loading command in the "after" directory was not sourced.

I fixed this in pathogen.vim by amending the `pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()` function to explicitly append all "after" directories found within bundle directories.

Here is a patch for pathogen.vim version 1.2:

```
121c121,125
<       let list +=  [dir] + pathogen#glob_directories(dir.sep.name.sep.'*[^~]')
---
>       let subdirs = pathogen#glob_directories(dir.sep.name.sep.'*[^~]')
>       let list += [dir]
>       for subdir in subdirs
>         let list += [subdir] + pathogen#glob_directories(subdir.sep.'*after*')
>       endfor
```

**BIG EDIT**: After coming across [this closed issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/closed#issue/4) on the Pathogen github site, I discovered that the root cause was not that the "after" directories needed to be added explicitly, but that they were not being added because of a backslash escaping issue on win32 systems in the `substitute()` command.

Here is a much more concise patch, and in unified format this time, sorry...

```
@@ -116,7 +116,8 @@
   let list = []
   for dir in pathogen#split(&rtp)
     if dir =~# '\<after$'
-      let list +=  pathogen#glob_directories(substitute(dir,'after$',name.sep.'*[^~]'.sep.'after','')) + [dir]
+      let replacement = substitute(name.sep.'*[^~]'.sep.'after', '\\', '\\\\', 'g')
+      let list +=  pathogen#glob_directories(substitute(dir,'after$',replacement,'')) + [dir]
     else
       let list +=  [dir] + pathogen#glob_directories(dir.sep.name.sep.'*[^~]')
     endif
```

The reporter of the github issue said that they sent Tim a pull request, and Tim said he accepted it, but the described change isn't in the current version of the code, so I thought I would do what I could to provide my solution here.

This patch escapes any backslashes in the glob. There shouldn't be any backslashes in any of the runtime path items on non-win32 systems in the first place, or if there are it is because +shellslash is set in vim and this escaping is probably required.

I'm leaving the old solution up there for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had to `chmod +x` sparkup's support script to make it work. Does Vim give you some error message?

Comment: I don't think zen-coding uses sparkup.  I installed the sparkup plugin and it worked.  Dunno what I was messing up with zen-coding, but I have zenness back in vim, which is the end goal.  Thanks.